# Laravel using Arabic characters as query parameters

Tags: php, laravel-5, lumen

I'm testing my Laravel Lumen API with Postman, my controller retrieve data from database using url query parameter like below

```
$router->get('/ByName/{contactGov}', 'ByNameController@list');
```

My url in Postman is http://localhost/apitest/public/ByName/BGD 
and every thing works fine but when i use Arabic characters like 
[http://localhost/apitest/public/ByName/بغداد](http://localhost/apitest/public/ByName/%D8%A8%D8%BA%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%AF)
 there will be no response with error :
There was an error connecting to http://localhost/apitest/public/ByName/%D8%A8%D8%BA%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%AF.

So what i'm missing

Answer (score 1):

try to send the parameters as get parameters,using postman Params .
also declare the Request to be able to access the parameters,or Input::get('name')

Answer (score 1):

After many years I found my question the solution is to use `urldecode` for arabic parameters like below :

Ex Route :

```
$router->get('List/{arabic_text_param}','Controller@List');
```

In Controller :

```
public function List($arabic_text_param){

$text = urldecode($arabic_text_param);

// Use it with your queries 

}
```

Hope to help someone